# Can't upload changes to ASP.NET - publish function doesn't upload changes

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have developed an asp.net application and when using the publish tool in Visual Studio 2008, my changes don't get uploaded to the server (ie new css files). I made a thread about this on asp.net and was told to clear my local settings folder in my documents/application data, but because I am on a networked pc at work, I don't have this folder. Is there another way to fix this?

Also, I tried to do a copy (tried anything out of desperation), but this won't work because the site is now precompiled.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages? does the publish succeed but you dont see the changes? try clearing the browser cache if it does, you may also need to force an app pool recycle.

Comment: No error messages. Nothing in any logs. The publish succeeds (everything in output is as it should be), but the new files and changes to existing files don't reach the server). So I don't think clearing the browser cache will fix the problem. App pool recycle maybe.

Comment: What happens if you tell it to delete the files before sending the new ones?

Comment: This is what I always do, when that dialog comes up. I choose to delete all, and then the output tells me the publish is in progress and the part of the project it is at. It seems like maybe the project is not being deleted and the code isn't being uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use FTP.  I personally never use "Publish", I use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for all my publishing needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to rule out permissions errors:

1. Navigate to the server virtual dir using unc paths
2. Edit a List item key value pair in the published web.config and check whether you are able to save the change
3. if that was successful try manually deleting all the files then publishing the changes.
4. if that still fails publish to a local folder then copy from the local folder to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeff Sheldon, I use Beyond Compare in my development environment to push to my development server.  When I'm ready to push to production though, I publish to another directory on my workstation and use Beyond Compare to push the compiled site to production.

Publish should copy everything that your solution sees.  If you add something to the directory structure outside of Visual Studio and don't refresh that directory in your solution, it may not get published.